# maven error - package org.junit does not exist

Tags: maven, testing, junit

I got a little trouble using maven and junit.
Running junit test on its own works perfect, but building with Maven `mvn clean test` fails. I made sure that all tests are within "src/test/java" and all sources are within "src/main/java", so junit can find them (regarding to other questions this was the problem in many other cases).

So does anybody knows why I this is not working for me?

### Error Message snipped:

```
/D:/pathToProject/myProject/src/test/java/myPackage/MyFile.java:[5,17] package org.junit does not exist
```

### Pom.xml Snipped:

```
<...project information.../>
  <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source />
                    <target />
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    <plugins>
    </plugins>
  </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: One wrong thing is: Why do you change the default location via `<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>` which does not make sense. Remove it. Furthermore i would suggest to use `<source>1.5</source>` and `<target>1.5</target>` at least or may be 1.6/1.7.

Comment: Thanks for your speedy answer. I already changed the source/target to 1.7, as lower versions were leading to other problems. I already thought of something like this and I will test it next week (since this is not really my project, but the one of my collegue -> he is at his vacations -> report the results next week)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Khmarbaise pointed you to a mistake, the fact that you've overwritten the src directory means that maven will try to compile your test classes in the `compile` phase, but would fail, as your jUnit dependency is given with the scope `test` and is available in [`test` phase](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Build_Lifecycle_Basics) only which comes later

Either remove the scope 'test' or change your source directory location so that it doesn't include your test classes